# Java - Show time & update time in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to get the time of the day to appear in a window using JOptionPane and to get the window to update the time when you press the OK button.

I get the time to appear but can not get it to update when I click the "OK" button..

Here is my code (im a beginner so it is a bit "messy", I know!)

```
package p2; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Exercise2b {
    private int hour;
    private int minute;
    private int second;

    public void demo() {

        String message1, message2;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
    message1 = "Klockan är "+hour+":"+minute+":"+second;
    message2 = toString();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message1);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);
    }

     public Exercise2b(int hour, int minute, int second) {
         this.hour = hour;
         this.minute = minute;
         this.second = second;
     }

        public Exercise2b() {
    }

        public int getHour() {
            return this.hour;
        }

        public int getMinute() {
            return this.minute;
        }

        public int getSecond() {
            return this.second;
        }
         public String toString() {
                return this.hour +":"+ this.minute+ ":"+ this.second + " ";
         }



      public static void main(String[] args) {
         Exercise2b prog = new Exercise2b();
         prog.demo();

     }



}
```

Comment: Where is your code to update when you click on ok?

Comment: Why not use `DateFormat`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating local variables instead of using the globals and also you need to assign the values from calendar again, otherwise the date will not change, because calendar is just a snapshot of the time, it's don't change, so you need to call `getInstance()` again.

Try doing this

```
     public void demo() {
        String message1, message2;
        message1 = "Klockan är " + getHour() + ":" + getMinute() + ":" +            getSecond();    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message1);  
        message2 = toString();      
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);
    }

    public int getHour() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    }

    public int getMinute() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.SECOND);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return getHour() + ":" + getMinute() + ":" + getSecond() + " ";
    }
```

Comment: **ou're creating local variables instead of using the globals and also you need to assign the values from calendar again, otherwise the date will not change.** I knew that there was something I totally forgot about and it was so obvious! Thank you very much Johnny! :)

Comment: @FR1TTE No problem, note that calendar doesn't change, like I described now.

Answer (score 0):

In the toString() you should obtain the current hours, minutes and seconds. Maybe you could extract this:

```
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

to a method, format as string and return (Calendar instance can be a field, as it is a pretty heavyweight object). That way you can reuse the logic in both demo() and toString() methods.